# DomCrawler after a certain tag take

Tags: php, parsing, dom, tags, domcrawler

I want to get the label after br

can be hlmt tag after br tag , or there may be no labels filter(div>br+*) is it a right choice ?

```
<tr class='detail'>
<div class='grid-5 mobile-grid-5' style='text-align:center;'><span style='font-weight: 
bold;'>1/X</span><br><span class='betred'>1.02</span></div>
<div class='grid-5 mobile-grid-5' style='text-align:center;'><span style='font-weight: 
bold;'>1/X</span><br>-</div>
</tr>
```

the code i wrote

```
$nodeValuess = $crawler->filter('tr.detail')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
$array = $node->filter('div>br+*')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
return $node->text();
});
 return $array;
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($nodeValuess);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.02
        )

)
```

i want to do

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.02
            [1] => -
        )

)
```

Comment: Your second case is just a naked text node on its own, `-`, so you can not select it this way - `*` selects an _element_ node with an arbitrary tag name, but there is none. You need to go via the `br` element here, and then get its sibling text node.

Comment: what kind of regulation is required in this case?